# rnw linebreak, tidy won't work

Tags: sweave, rnw

I am new to R noweb. Actually, it is my first Rnw file (about 200 lines now, and Rnw is awesome!).
My Problem: I have a couple of very long chunk lines, that exceed the paper. I have spent quite a long time on that now, and have of course stumbled over "tidy=TRUE". But that somehow won't work.

Here is a working example, which exceeds the paper in the pdf:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
<<example, tidy = TRUE>>=
1.111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
@
\end{document}
```

I am using R studio version 0.98.1103 and MiKTeX 2.9.

What do I do wrong? And how do I do it right?

Any help is highly appreciated!
Serijoscha

Comment: Is tidy only for knitr? But if so, how can the problem be solved with Sweave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a very long time, I finally found the answer:

The `tidy=TRUE` chunk argument is only for knitr.

For Sweave, `keep.source=FALSE` can be used instead.